Unable to add multiple existing data disks to vm using azure bicep
Unable to add multiple existing data disks to vm using azure bicep.
Param data disk id array
Under vm module
data disk:[
Existing data disk id
]
Its says invalid deployment
Unable to add multiple existing data disks to vm using azure bicep

Show your template please.

Param existingdiskid array = [ 'disk1', 'disk2', 'disk3', 'disk4']

Follow this way, fill-in missing values for vm. Have not been test at my side, but it should work

param disk1Name string = 'disk1'
param disk2Name string = 'disk2'
param disk3Name string = 'disk3'
param disk4Name string = 'disk4'

resource disk1 'Microsoft.Compute/disks@2023-10-02' existing = {
  name: disk1Name
}

resource disk2 'Microsoft.Compute/disks@2023-10-02' existing = {
  name: disk2Name
}

resource disk3 'Microsoft.Compute/disks@2023-10-02' existing = {
  name: disk3Name
}

resource disk4 'Microsoft.Compute/disks@2023-10-02' existing = {
  name: disk4Name
}

resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'xxx'
  location: 'xxx'
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: 'xxx'
    }
    osProfile: {
      computerName: 'xxx'
      adminUsername: 'xxx'
      adminPassword: 'xxx'
    }
    storageProfile: {
      imageReference: {
        publisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsServer'
        offer: 'WindowsServer'
        sku: 'xxxx'
        version: 'latest'
      }
      osDisk: {
        createOption: 'FromImage'
        managedDisk: {
          storageAccountType: 'StandardSSD_LRS'
        }
      }
      dataDisks: [
        {
          createOption: 'Attach'
          lun: 0
          managedDisk: {
            id: disk1.id
          }
        }
        {
          createOption: 'Attach'
          lun: 1
          managedDisk: {
            id: disk2.id
          }
        }
        {
          createOption: 'Attach'
          lun: 2
          managedDisk: {
            id: disk3.id
          }
        }
        {
          createOption: 'Attach'
          lun: 3
          managedDisk: {
            id: disk4.id
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    networkProfile: {
      networkInterfaces: [
        {
          id: 'xxx'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}



Thanks for your response. Now iam getting error property not allowed datadisk. Name
